# ICal timezone setting doesn't work on DTEND on android, outlook and gmail works

Tags: android, calendar, outlook, icalendar

When i open my ics file on an android device, the dtstart date is showing right, but the dtend is showing in a different timezone (+1 or +2 hours). When I open the ics directly on gmail.com or outlook the dtend date is correctly showed. What's wrong with my code?

for a full ics file, click here: http://bcaeternitas.nl/modules/mod_blank15v52/tmpl/kalender.php?plg_ID=2469&cmp_ID=492&org_ID=4&team=Speelschema%20Heren%201

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
PRODID:-//BC Aeternitas//iCal 1.0//NL
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:Basketbalschema
X-WR-RELCALID:8CC55934-A799-4615-9175-F84C7E05C8CA
X-APPLE-CALENDAR-COLOR:#F57802
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Amsterdam
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19810329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19961027T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20130922T000000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20130922T010000
SUMMARY:BC Heeze H1 - Aeternitas H1
LOCATION:Heeze De Pompenmaker
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine too me. Why don't you try to use a DURATION ([RFC5545#section-3.8.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.5)) instead of a DTEND, e.g.

```
DURATION:PT1H
```

for a 1 hour event.

Answer (score 0):

i experienced this also with a Samsung calendar app, you can verify installing the Google calendar app in parallel and see if it displays the dates correctly. 
If yes and as both use the same calendar storage on the device it is a glitch in Samsung calendar with timezone handling as in my case it was displaying the date in a different timezone (the timestamp was correct but not matching to the displayed timezone)